# Using recursion multiple times to find a mean

Tags: expectation, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation

I had a general question regarding a statement in statistics; it is for no assignment or examination. The setting is this, we know that for given random variables $X$ and $Y$, we can compute $E[X]=E\big[E[X|Y]\big]$.

We would see the above statement in most basic classes. Now, suppose we have $X,Y,$ and $Z$; can we then say that $E[X] = E\bigg[E\big[E[X|Y]\big]\bigg|Z\bigg]$?

Comment: $E[E[X \mid Y] \mid Z]=E[X \mid Y,Z]$. So yes, it follows from the ordinary tower property (where we condition on $\sigma$-algebras).

Comment: Hello Ian, I was curious what is the "tower property" and if I understand well it is just a synonym of iterated expectation (correct me if I am wrong). In my classes, we were never told it is also called that way. So more generally, we can have $X,Y,Z,V,W$ (or a sequence) and say $E[X]=E[X|Y,Z,V,W]$. Thank you very much !

Comment: The tower property is another name for the property $E[E[X \mid \dots]]=E[X]$. It does not matter what "$\dots$" is.

Comment: Cool, that is awesome just learned something new. Thank you very much again